# Font smoothing in Visual Studio for Mac 2019

Tags: visual-studio-mac, font-smoothing

I upgraded Visual Studio for Mac 2017 to 2019 yesterday, and immediately noticed that the Subpixel rendering is switched off inside the text editor! It looks terrible.

I'm running OS X Mojave where I, after having upgraded it, explicitly turned subpixel rendering on again for the entire system using a guide I found on the net. So everything else than the VS for Mac 2019 text editor windows themselves is using subpixel rendering.

What's going on, and how do I turn it back on? I have searched the net for an hour now and found no clue or hack.